# Count ways of coloring m grey blocks with red color, in which red blocks should be in groups with count at least n

Tags: c++

I want to calculate ways of coloring i black blocks with white color, in which red blocks should be in groups with count at least j.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: Atleast Show something what you have tried yet

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of a blind homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying to program this yourself. To fix that, please have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `C(m)` be the number of ways of colouring `m` blocks (fixing `n`).

If `m<n`, then `C(m)=1`, since no red blocks can appear.

Otherwise, a colouring either ends in a grey block, is all red, or ends with a grey block followed by `n` or more red blocks.

That is, if `m>=n`, `C(m)=C(m-1)+1+sum(C(m-i-1) for i=n..m-1)`. Rewriting this gives `C(m)=1+C(m-1)+sum(C(i) for i=0..(m-n-1))`.

With a bit of care, we can compute this in O(m) time and space. The care is needed to note that the sum can be incrementally computed.

Here's one way to do it (python, but should be easy to convert to whatever language you want):

```
def count(m, n):
    C = [0] * (m+1)
    s = 0
    for i in range(m+1):
        if i-n-1 >= 0:
            s += C[i-n-1]
        C[i] = 1 if i<n else C[i-1] + 1 + s
    return C[m]

print(count(7, 3))
```

With a little more care, we can note that we only access the last `n+1` elements of `C` at any point in time, so we can reduce the space usage to O(n):

```
def count(m, n):
    C = [0] * (n+1)
    s = 0
    for i in range(m+1):
        if i-n-1 >= 0:
            s += C[(i-n-1)%(n+1)]
        C[i%(n+1)] = 1 if i<n else C[(i+n)%(n+1)] + 1 + s
    return C[m%(n+1)]

print(count(7, 3))
```

Comment: Output of `count(1, 0)` should be `2`. Your algorithm gives `3`.

Comment: @NimaHeydariNasab I think you can fix it by just adding `n = max(n, 1)` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Yes, the code assumes n>0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible program for that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int count_rec(int m, int n, std::vector<int>& cache)
{
    // Count starts with 1 for no blocks filled
    int c = 1;
    // i = starting position of current block
    for (int i = 0; i <= m - n; i++)
    {
        // j = number of filled blocks
        for (int j = n; j <= m - i; j++)
        {
            // r = number of blocks available after this block
            int r = m - j - i;
            // Check if number of combinations for r has already been calculated
            if (cache[r] < 0)
            {
                // If not calculate (subtract 1 block gap)
                cache[r] = count_rec(r - 1, n, cache);
            }
            // Get cached value
            c += cache[r];
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int count(int m, int n)
{
    if (m <= 0) return 0;
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    std::vector<int> cache(m, -1);
    return count_rec(m, n, cache);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "count(7, 3) = " << count(7, 3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
count(7, 3) = 17
```

Comment: Output of `count(1, 0)` should be `2`. Your algorithm gives `1`.

Comment: @NimaHeydariNasab Right, made a mistake in the conditions in `count`, I think it's fine now.